# How could I pick a random item from a slice with bias towards one end of the slice using Go?

Tags: go, random, statistics, normal-distribution

I understand one way to pick a random value from a `slice` in `Go`:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())     
                                                
var db [500]string                         
log.Println(db[rand.Intn(len(db))])
```

But how would I pick a random item from the `slice`, with a bias towards one end of the `slice`? For my use case I'll have a `slice` that grows over time using `append()`. My understanding is that the newest items will be added to the right-hand side of the `slice`. I'd like to create a function that picks a random item from the `slice`, with bias towards the newest members of the `slice`. My first guess is to use a `normal distribution` via `rand.NormFloat64()`, but I'm not sure how or if I can use it to achieve this.

The function should be capable of picking any item from the `slice`, but should pick new items added to the `slice` at a much higher frequency.

Comment: How much higher frequency? What distribution are you targeting? Is a normal distribution what you want? If so, what is your question around using `NormFloat64`?

Comment: The ideal function would have adjustable frequency. But we could maybe say that Item's at the right-end of the slice should be chosen 10 times for often than items on the left-side. I'm not sure if I want a "normal" distribution actually. My question about `NormFloat64` is whether or not it's suitable/capable of achieving my goal. After some research I think I might need to create a `truncated normal distribution`.

Comment: You need to decide what type of distribution you want. If a normal distribution is fine, then `NormFloat64` does exactly what you want.

Comment: a [Beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) might be close to what you want.  that said, Go's `rand` module doesn't seem to include any of the useful statistical building blocks that would make this easy.  I can't even see a weighted choice function which would seem useful to implement

Comment: As an example of this [306 327 177 146 125 346 368 439 428 428 444 360 345 146 499  93 349 312 126 422] are 20 draws from the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) language `rbinom(20, 500, rbeta(20, 2, 0.9))` that makes this sort of thing easy.  you can see that most are up near 500 and there are a couple near 100.

Comment: Go isn't going to have this implemented in the std library, that's outside the scope of the language. You need to look at external projects like [`gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat`](https://pkg.go.dev/gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat), which also includes a number of distribution and sampling packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with the normal distribution, you can use rand.Normfloat64().  If your array has 20 items:

```
int(math.Abs(rand.NormFloat64())*10) % 20
```

Will produce numbers that are weighted toward the start of the list.  And

```
20 - int(math.Abs(rand.NormFloat64())*10) % 20
```

Will produce numbers that are weighted toward the end of the list.

Here's an example that demonstrates a sample random distribution.
On go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/AwEPEzQO7P8

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
)
func main() {
    var buckets [20]int
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        r := int(math.Abs(rand.NormFloat64())*10) % 20
        buckets[r]++
    }
    fmt.Println(buckets)
}
```

Sample output:

[86 92 76 80 73 69 60 69 58 51 47 38 44 30 29 24 19 27 18 10]

It's random though, so you could still get all tail end items ....

If you want a step function where the numbers of the first half are 10x the numbers of the left, just use two rands.

```
n := rand.Intn(10)
if rand.Float64() < 0.1 {
    n = n + 10
}
```

Example on go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/CitUsHmwQez

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    var buckets [20]int
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        r := rand.Intn(10)
        if rand.Float64() < 0.1 {
            r = r + 10
        }
        buckets[r]++
    }
    fmt.Println(buckets)
}
```

Sample output

[96 92 89 89 88 78 95 86 83 98 15 10 15 10 10 12 4 11 11 8]